# iOS Tableview cell in different section row has the same layout

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a problem and the best way to describe it is to show you pictures.
The last row of the section should get a glossy style and text-align center.
First i have a table with one section like that:

http://image-upload.de/image/RL93lJ/58f2422d97.png

but when i add another section to the top i get something like that:

http://image-upload.de/image/JggrVq/6ee42a1089.png

Here is the code in short form:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellOrder";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cellIsLastOne == TRUE) {

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
        //name


        cell.textLabel.text = @"Bezahlt";
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        cell.textLabel.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:25];

        cell.textLabel.textColor =  [UIColor whiteColor];

        //Glossy
        CALayer *thisLayer = cell.layer;
        if (thisLayer.sublayers.count == 1) {
            CAGradientLayer *glossLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
            glossLayer.frame = CGRectMake(cell.bounds.origin.x + cellOffset, cell.bounds.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width - cellOffset * 2, cellItemHeight);
            glossLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.4f].CGColor,
                                 (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.2f].CGColor,
                                 (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.75f alpha:0.0f].CGColor,
                                 (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.2f].CGColor,
                                 nil];
            glossLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f],
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f],
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f],
                                    nil];
            [thisLayer addSublayer:glossLayer];
        }

    } else {
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        ItemID;

        cell.textLabel.text = @"Name";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Price";
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


        cell.textLabel.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:20];
        cell.detailTextLabel.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:20];

        cell.textLabel.textColor =  [UIColor whiteColor];

    }

    cell.detailTextLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.4];
    cell.textLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.4];

    cell.detailTextLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);
    cell.textLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.72 green:0.76 blue:0.03 alpha:1.0];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    return cell;
```

I really don´t get the issue. Please help me. Thanks! ;)

Comment: Can I see the code to generate ```cellIsLastOne```?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem that your screenshots exhibit indicates that your calculation of `cellIsLastOne` is wrong.

But even if it were right, this would have a lot of problems when you scrolled through the table view, because the cells are being re-used. To fix, you can either:

- Use a different re-use identifier for the glossy cells
- Remove the glossy sublayers in the `else` block

Basically, when you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`, it might return a cell to which you'd previously added the glossy layers. Furthermore, this could add the glossy layers more than once.

Comment: Thanks for that advise! but even when i change the identifier to a unique string like that: NSString *CellIdentifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d%d",indexPath.row,indexPath.section]; it is not working :/

Comment: @user2630406 You don't want to do that; then you'd never re-use any cells at all. The problem you're describing has to do with `cellIsLastOne`. That's a fix for another problem that you'll have later, if your table view grows large enough to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I edit your code that may help you.

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellOrder";
    static NSString *glowCellIdentifier = @"glowCellOrder";
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    if (cellIsLastOne == TRUE) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:glowCellIdentifier];
    } else {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

     if (cell == nil) {
          if (cellIsLastOne == TRUE) {
             cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:glowCellIdentifier];  
             cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
          } else {
             cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
             cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
          }
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

    if (cellIsLastOne == TRUE) {
        //name

        cell.textLabel.text = @"Bezahlt";
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        cell.textLabel.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:25];

        cell.textLabel.textColor =  [UIColor whiteColor];

        //Glossy
        CALayer *thisLayer = cell.layer;
        if (thisLayer.sublayers.count == 1) {
            CAGradientLayer *glossLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
            glossLayer.frame = CGRectMake(cell.bounds.origin.x + cellOffset, cell.bounds.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width - cellOffset * 2, cellItemHeight);
            glossLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.4f].CGColor,
                                 (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.2f].CGColor,
                                 (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.75f alpha:0.0f].CGColor,
                                 (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.2f].CGColor,
                                 nil];
            glossLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f],
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f],
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f],
                                    nil];
            [thisLayer addSublayer:glossLayer];
        }

    } else {       

        ItemID;

        cell.textLabel.text = @"Name";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Price";
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


        cell.textLabel.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:20];
        cell.detailTextLabel.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:20];

        cell.textLabel.textColor =  [UIColor whiteColor];

    }

    cell.detailTextLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.4];
    cell.textLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.4];

    cell.detailTextLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);
    cell.textLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.72 green:0.76 blue:0.03 alpha:1.0];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    return cell;
```

This code is efficient to reuse cell and save memory.